# Redirect JSP page wrong extension

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a redirection once a transaction is performed, though the transaction never gets executed. The most surprising thing is that when I click a submit button I do get this cloaked URL redirection which I do not understand why?
My controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveCyclosUsers")
    public ModelAndView saveCyclosUsersCredentials(@ModelAttribute("cyclosUsers") CyclosUsers cyclosUsers, BindingResult bindingResult)
    {
        cyclosUsersService.saveCyclosUsers(cyclosUsers);
        System.out.println("Cyclos Users List:");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect/cyclosUsersList.html");   
    }
```

My JSP page:

```
<c:url var="userRegistration" value="saveCyclosUsers.html"/>
<form:form id="registerForm" modelAttribute="cyclosUsers" method="post" action="${userRegistration}">
```

The DAO code:

```
@Override
    public void saveCyclosUsers(CyclosUsers cyclosUsers) {
        //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(cyclosUsers);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO lower_credit WHERE" +"WEB-INF.views.Register.ownerName.selectedItem =" + "owner_name");
    }
```

Once i click on the submit button this is what error I do get: 
type Status report

```
message /CyclosProjectOnOverdraft/WEB-INF/views/redirect/cyclosUsersList.html.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
```

The extensions is the problem **"cyclosUsersList.html.jsp"** , html.jsp. I think it's weird. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:cyclosUsersList.html"); // Not redirect/cyclosUsersList.html
```

Comment: Thanks, Loc.The problem is solved. When I run the code now its gives this error: "org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of nigeria.development.foundation.entity.CyclosUsers.creditLimit". I know that the problem is with my DAO save method I wrote because it is to accept 2 input but I specified one there, correct me by suggesting the right code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a ViewResolver in your spring mvc applicationContext with the suffix set to '.jsp'.
So spring by default appends '.jsp' to your view name.

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix">
              <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
           </property>
          <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
    </bean>
```

To avoid using a view resolver you could directly return a 'View' object, then no view resolver is used. You could also use @ResponseBody, then view resolver is bypassed.

Comment: thanks. Please kindly help me review the insert statement in the DAO file. It is not performing the insert as it ought to. What i want to do is to compare insert a new credit_limit for the selected user from the dropdown box on the JSP page.